# Date criteria is not working after specific date

Tags: date, ms-access

I'm making the Stock Management program by MS Access.
And now I'm facing the problem about 'Date Criteria'.

```
    BAL_Order_Mngt: _
    Nz(DSum("[Qty_Total]","qryOrderDetail","[StockIDFK]=" & [StockID] & _
    " AND [ShippngDate]<=" & Format([StockReleaseCostMonthEnd],"\#yyyy-mm-dd\#") & _
    " AND [LocationCodeFK]=" & [LocationID])/DLookUp("[UOM_Rate_Impt]","qryOrderDetail", _
    "[StockIDFK]=" & [StockID]),0)
```

With this code, if [ShippingDate] is earlier than [StockReleaseCostMonthEnd], then the stock all quantity of each item before the specific date should be summed.
The problem is the period before the end of September'16 is working very well,
but the period from October'16 is not working as below picture

[Date Criteria is not working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSmIc.png)

Could any body help me to solve this problem?
Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Don't format the date in the expression, that is, don't use the Format function. It turns the date into a string so you're comparing strings instead of date values.

```
BAL_Order_Mngt: _
Nz(DSum("[Qty_Total]","qryOrderDetail","[StockIDFK]=" & [StockID] & _
" AND [ShippngDate]<= [StockReleaseCostMonthEnd] & _
" AND [LocationCodeFK]=" & [LocationID])/DLookUp("[UOM_Rate_Impt]","qryOrderDetail", _
"[StockIDFK]=" & [StockID]),0)
```

Comment: Hi, Dale ! Thank you !
Yes. I solved this problem to change from the Date to Number as using Clng function.